# KenBurnsView how to set image resource?

Tags: android-animation, android, android-kenburnsview

I'm trying to use [Faria's KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) library in my application.

KenBurnsView is some extension of ImageView, with a nice animating effect. You may have seen the effect in Foursquare app's images.

For the actual picture, the view uses the XML defined "android:src" property.
But I want to set the image resource during run-time through Java code. I have tried setImageResource, setBackgroundResource, set".."drawabale and many other methods. But no matter what, my image setting command always makes my app crash at run-time.

I've been searching the web for a couple of hours for any trace of discussion on KenBurnsView but have had no luck whatsoever.

### My question is:

How is it possible to **set the image property of KenBurnsView on run-time**?

### EDIT :

Here's the stack trace:

```
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): Process: com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.sample, PID: 16712
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.sample/com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.sample.SingleImageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.MathUtils.getRectRatio(MathUtils.java:44)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.RandomTransitionGenerator.generateRandomRect(RandomTransitionGenerator.java:93)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.RandomTransitionGenerator.generateNextTransition(RandomTransitionGenerator.java:64)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView.startNewTransition(KenBurnsView.java:207)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView.handleImageChange(KenBurnsView.java:280)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView.setImageResource(KenBurnsView.java:126)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.sample.SingleImageActivity.onCreate(SingleImageActivity.java:36)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
06-16 01:26:43.062: E/AndroidRuntime(16712):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Looks like `setImageResource()` should work. Please edit your question to add the crash strack trace.

Comment: @matiash: Edited. Have you ever tried to do the thing I can't?

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate if you could help me towards my goal in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the call stack, I'd say this is a bug in the library. It's not updating the `mDrawableRect` immediately after a new drawable is set.

Try changing the implementation of `setImageResource()` to add call `updateDrawableBounds()`, i.e.

```
@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    updateDrawableBounds(); // <- added line
    handleImageChange();
}
```

Looks like this should fix the problem (but I haven't tested it).

**EDIT** Actually, all the `setImage<X>()` methods seem to have this issue. So the same fix should be used for `setImageDrawable()`, `setImageBitmap()`, and `setImageURI()`.

**NEWEST EDIT** This is now fixed, according to @FlávioFaria himself. Just update to version 1.0.3.

Comment: Hi, @Campiador . How did you load your image? Is it from drawable or from url? Because I have a similar problem to yours, but I'm loading from url. Tried the solution but still it persists.

Comment: I pushed some changes that fix this error. You can download v1.0.3 and it'll work fine.

Comment: @FlávioFaria I'm glad. How about an upvote for being on support duty? ;)

Comment: Sorry, here it goes my upvote! Helping people is always rewarding.

Comment: @FlávioFaria Hahah, you're absolutely right (and please, why sorry?) Thank you very much sir :)